# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{2n^n\over (n+1)^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm stuck in this question, how can I find the limit below? 
 $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{2n^n\over (n+1)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(2n^n)\over (n+1)^{n+1}}$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(2n)^n\over (n+1)^{n+1}}$?

Comment: the first one, as I wrote there

Comment: When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Sorry @N.F.Taussig it's my first time here and I didn't know that, I'll make sure I do this next time I post a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{2n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{2}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$$

Comment: So is the answer $0$?

Answer (score 1):

After the hint from @5xum I could solve the question, so here is the answer:

$$\frac{2n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{2}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}$$

so we have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2}{n+1}}\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2}{n+1}} = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{(\frac{n}{n+1})^n}= \lim_{n\to \infty}{(\frac{n+1}{n})^{-n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n}} = \frac{1}{e}$$

so
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{2n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}} = 0\cdot {\frac{1}{e}} = 0$$